# CPQ - How to conditionally renderig fields on quote edit lines

Tags: community, cpq, quote, quotelineitem, rendering

[image]

I want to render the Contracted price term field on quote edit line drawer based on Product Family

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the Page Security plugin capabilities and implement the `isFieldVisible` method to apply your logic

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.cpq_dev_plugins.meta/cpq_dev_plugins/cpq_javascript_page_security_plugin.htm